# Store Identity UserId in separate table upon first login in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure

Upon using one of the identity providers (facebook, google etc.) to **login for the first time** on azure mobile services I would like to **store a record of the user's account in a custom user table** in order that I could traverse this table using a Scheduled job at intervals. How could I capture the login on the server side to insert/create the Users table.

Just to clarify: I don't want to wait for the user to add a record to a table themselves and then leverage the server side insert procedure of that command. I want to do this initially on first logon.

<strike>Is there a way to override the identity login somehow?</strike>

Many thanks,

Tomás

Answer (score 1):

You could create a server script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    item.owner = user.userId; //your user
    request.execute();
}
```

for more information about WAMS Server scripts:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/validate-modify-and-augment-data-dotnet/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj591477.aspx

Comment: Just to add one more clarification for the second part of the question: NO, you cannot override identity login by anyway. This would be a major security issue if you could.

Comment: Thank you both. @Thiago: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I want to create a record in the user table as soon as the user logs in for the first time. I don't want to wait for them to initiate the adding of a record to a table before doing so. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Tomás Are you using C#? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/  In the Authenticate method, you could insert a record in a table as you want.

Comment: @Thiago Thanks Thiago, I had considered that but for no particular reason would have preferred to do it on the server side. I'm like a dog with a bone now and won't let it slide...that said however, I may have to go with this option.

Comment: Take a look at Windows Azure Mobile services Academy and channel 9 videos, maybe it will help you too. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K099Vz9mdNQ and http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

Comment: Ok. I'm gunna go with doing this from the client i.e. When user first logs in do a select from my custom "accounts" table and if no row is found for the userId then do an insert into that same table. I came across this Doto sample Windows 8 App project where in order to store additional profile information they took this approach. He is the link to that project: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Doto-Windows-Azure-Mobile-d960601f  Thanks guys.